# Как получить результат покупки Billing?

Tags: android, android-billing

Есть кнопка, по нажатию на которую появляется окно покупки. После совершения платежа окно пропадает. Как мне получить этот момент когда окно пропадает и покупка была совершенна?

`onProductPurchased()`, работает только при повторном запуске Billing (в том случае если в первый раз покупка была произведена).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `onActivityResult` можно отловить, следуя [документации](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (requestCode == 1001) {
      int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
      String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
      String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            String sku = jo.getString("productId");
            alert("Вы купили " + sku);
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
             alert("Ошибка при расшифровке данных о покупке.");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Для библиотеки github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3 есть же [пример](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/sample/src/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/sample2/MainActivity.java#L61), когда `BillingProcessor` создаёте, перегружаете метод `onProductPurchased`:

```
bp = new BillingProcessor(this, LICENSE_KEY, MERCHANT_ID, new BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
                showToast("onProductPurchased: " + productId);
                updateTextViews();
            }
      [...]
      });
```

Comment: @xTIGRx там же в примере есть https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/sample/src/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/sample2/MainActivity.java#L61

Comment: Странно, я вроде написал и через минуту удалил свой коммент, так как нашел там